# How can I merge a sequence of objects with repeating keys into one?

Tags: json, jq

I have a sequence of objects, each with a single key. The values are themselves objects and the keys in the sequence may repeat. I would like to group said objects by their key and merge the values for repeated keys with something like jq's `add`.

More generally I want to

```
1. Group by key
2. Perform some op on array of values under matching keys
3. Get object with all unique keys from input with values the results of step 2
```

Here is my input:

```json
# jq '.' /tmp/json.json 
{
  "cmsa-x-41100001": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100001.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.10"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "cmsa-x-41100002": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100002.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.5"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "cmsa-x-41100000": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100000.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.13"
    ]
  }
}
{
  "cmsa-x-41100001": {
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  }
}
{
  "cmsa-x-41100002": {
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  }
}
{
  "cmsa-x-41100000": {
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  }
}
```

Here is my desired output:

```json
{
  "cmsa-x-41100000": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100000.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.13"
    ],
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  },
  "cmsa-x-41100001": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100001.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.10"
    ],
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  },
  "cmsa-x-41100002": {
    "fqdn": "cmsa-x-41100002.example.com",
    "fqdn_ip4": [
      "100.64.40.5"
    ],
    "k8s_salt:cluster_domain": "cluster4.csip"
  }
}
```

I have managed to achieve this with

```
jq -s 'map(to_entries[0]) | group_by(.key) | map(.[0].value = (map(.value) | add) ) | map(.[0]) | from_entries' /tmp/json.json
```

but it seems ugly and I feel, I'm doing it the wrong way. How would this be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` to fold all the objects together, and merge their contents with the `*` operator:

```
reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)
```

Comment: `jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' /tmp/json.json` works like a charm. No idea why `jq 'reduce . as $item ({}; . * $item)' /tmp/json.json` does not, however. Regardless, +1 and accept, thanks a bunch.